# Modify an excel file using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, excel

I am trying to write on an existing excel file where my data is coming as a json format. I want to load the excel file then write on it and then have to download it. I have searched a lot and there are lots of solution but they are not working for me. People are using xlsx, sheetjs to solve that type of problem .Now I just want to read my excel file but when I try read the file , it throw me the below error [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKdbg.png)

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import excel from 'xlsx';

function App() {
  const read_file=()=>{
    console.log("hi")
    var wb = excel.readFile('Book1.xlsx')
    console.log(wb)
  }
 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button type="button" onClick={read_file()}>button</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```